# What are the deployment differences between Hosted vs Internal PBX?

Tags: asterisk, sip, nat, pbx, freepbx

I'm trying to get a non-sales biased answer between deployment needs for hosted vs inhouse (FreePBX with SIP Trunking) PBX. We will only have about 20 handsets in the office, and probably a max of 5 concurrent calls (talkpaths/channels) so it seems like a hosted PBX is a viable option.

With a hosted solution is it merely a matter of plugging in the SIP phones to the network, configuring the phones and PBX and its ready to go? If not, does it require an edge device (SBC) also? Or, can a SMB router provide handle the NAT and security needed for SIP/RTP? I've been led to believe that if we run our own PBX then a SBC is necessary under all circumstances for security and quality while others say it isn't for the small traffic volume we will have.

Aside from the ability to customize the PBX beyond what a hosted solution provides and the ability to scale to more traffic, is there any practical reason to operate our own PBX if we're looking for a quick deployment route? Is the call quality and reliability typically distinctly better using a SIP Trunk as opposed to a hosted solution?

We've read and been told conflicting things regarding what need to do to deploy a hosted PBX vs our own so we're hoping someone with experience can bring clarity to what the typical process to deploy a hosted PBX involves in terms of the hardware (handsets) and local network (router and/or SBC to handle the NAT).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SBC, you are too small. NAT should be handled by PBX either hosted or your own.

So forget about all fancy words, like SBC and etc, you don't need it for 20 extension, all what you need is PBX.

If you choose hosted, then all what you need is just plug in phones, configure them and they should work. Off cause there might pop-up some network related issues, but generally all should work without any issue.

If you have resources and knowledge(or willingness to learn) regarding FreePBX, then you might choose your own PBX, if not - use hosted PBX, there is dozens options. I don't think there is a big reason to have own PBX instead of hosted, personally I will prefer my own FreePBX running on digitalocean and it will cost me 5-20$ per month, but if you don't have knowledge and willingness to deal with it, maybe hosted PBX is best option for you. Keep in mind that there is dozens hosted PBX and they differs a lot. Some providers might be better then others and some might be not reliable.

Off cause you need to think about security if you don't have any knowledge what you are doing and you don't have any person who can help you with securing your PBX, then there is only one option - using hosted PBX, but again it will not eliminate all risks. If you will decide to go with stupidly simple password, then there is nobody to blame, only you.

If you decide to go with your own PBX then FreePBX is only one option I believe.

Comment: We are software developers but not network engineers, which is why I pose these questions. I'm comfortable with configuring a PBX, but the network side of things is where we've found conflicting information. One vendor insisted we'd need an SBC if we want to do run our own PBX and get a SIP trunk from them. Some hosted vendors insist we need a router that is SIP or H.323 compatible, while others insist you can just plug and play the phones into any router (well a switch in our case, connected to the router) and its good to go. The security is something most had trouble explaining.

Comment: Regarding security, we couldn't get a straight answer if the signaling was encrypted (I would assume this should be standard at this point for hosted PBXs?) and if the stream was also encrypted. Our assumption, but one we were trying to confirm, is the main security concern in a hosted PBX is the endpoint credentials. But so long as they are strong PWs (not a brute force candidate) and the signaling is encrypted that we should not typically have other glaring security issues to consider as far as VoIP is concerned?

Comment: `One vendor insisted we'd need an SBC if we want to do run our own PBX and get a SIP trunk from them.` - First time I read something like this, either that person is just don't know what he is telling you or he tries to sell you something what you don't need. Regarding compatible router - sometimes it is better to have simple router, which do nothing, then this "compatible" router cause this compatible can do some funny stuff with SIP packets and at the end broke signaling. But it is only a case if you do not encrypt signalling. I believe regular router will work for almost anybody.

Comment: If you will go with hosted, then only thing what you should concern is strong passwords. I believe if you are regular person then you don't need VoIP encryption. In any case even if you get encryption most of VoIP providers do not use them, so when you will call-out to outside your PBX all your encryption will be more or less useless.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no dedicated admin, go hosted version.

Only go local version if you have bad internet connection and need in multiple calls inside company.

Comment: Hosted solution is better option for this.